# fyne-cross windows compiled from linux blocked by windows defender (trojan alert)

Tags: go, fyne

I cross-compiled a simple software from linux to windows through Fyne.

The software is pretty easy and straightforward, it just creates QR codes from an input given by the user, nothing special.
It works flawlessly but Windows Defender wakes up and alerts me there's a trojan, and it eventually deletes the .exe.

For more context, I didn't sign the software while compiling it. But I don't really need to distribute it, it's just a utility I'm going to use privately.

Any of you guys has experienced this issue before? Could be related to the cross-compiling procedure? Or maybe a sign is mandatory? Can depend by the QR code library I'm using, since it's the unique non-standard library I included?

Answer (score 0):

There have been many reports of Go applications triggering windows virus detection, this is a problem with more than just your cross-compiled app.
As we live in a “default virus” world the defender rules need to understand Go apps, which has not yet happened.
In the meantime the only way to resolve this is to sign your apps I think.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll try to sign it and I'll let you know.